# Extract date time from Apache Combined log format using AWS Logs and Cloudwatch

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We're using [awslogs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/EC2NewInstanceCWL.html) to collect Apache Combined formatted logs into [Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/). It's all capturing fine, but we're getting `timestamp could not be parsed from message` error.

An example log entry:

`::ffff:10.0.0.1 - blahblah [17/Aug/2017:20:31:07 +0000] "GET /favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://blahblah:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"`

Our config for this set of log files looks like this, including our `datetime_format` entry:

`[access_logs]
log_group_name = cromwell
log_stream_name = react-172.31.43.245-access
file = /home/admin/aperian-react/log/*access.log
datetime_format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H%M:%S %z"
multi_line_start_pattern = ::ffff:
time_zone = UTC
encoding = ascii`

As you can see, the datetime is mid-line. This is different from most examples for syslogs, etc. We could change our log format, but we'd prefer not to since they flow into other systems as well.

Answer (score 4):

Our dateformat_string was missing a colon.

```
datetime_format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H%M:%S %z"  # wrong
datetime_format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z" # correct
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want `"` around the value

Comment: Thanks. That didn’t have an impact on the parsing and intake into awslogs.